# optgroup prevents jquery from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following Jquery line does not seem to take effect when `optgroup` is added to select.

```
$('#desire_candidate > option').removeAttr("selected");
```

HTML

```
<select name="desire_candidate" id="desire_candidate">
      <option id="selected1" style="color:gray" selected>Select below</option>
         <!-- Categorize select options -->
         <optgroup label="Web">
             <option class="desire_candidate" value="Entry level Frontend Developer">Entry level Frontend Developer</option>
             <option class="desire_candidate" value="Entry level Backend Developer">Entry level Backend Developer</option>
         </optgroup>

         <optgroup label="Mobile">
            <option class="desire_candidate" value="Entry level iOS Developer">Entry level iOS Developer</option>
             <option class="desire_candidate" value="Entry level Android Developer">Entry level Android Developer</option>
         </optgroup>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
// Previous button
$('#previous1').click(function(){

    // Hide current stage
    $('#step2').css('display', 'none');

    // Display previous stage
    $('#step1').css('display', 'block');

    // Reset selected option to default
    $('#desire_candidate > option').removeAttr("selected");
    //$('#selected1').Attr("selected");


    });
```

Comment: thanks that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because option is no longer a direct child of the select box anymore.

The `>` symbol means the next following selector is a direct descendant of the preceding selector.

You can either use `#desire_candidate option` as the selector, which will look for any `option` within the select. Or `#desire_candidate > optgroup > option` which will only look for options that are within optgroups

Use whichever one suits your needs best.

[CSS Child Combinators reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)